# Sum of two compact sets is compact

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

I didn't find an already existing proof for the following question:

We have two compact sets $A, B \subset \Bbb R^n$. I want to show that the addition of these is also compact.

So, I want to show $A+B:=\{a+b: a\in A, b\in B \}$ is compact.

Please help me.

Comment: What is the definition you know for compactness? Because if it is the finite subcover one, this shouldn't prove to be terribly hard...

Comment: I think it is easy with sequential compactness and harder with open cover definition.

Comment: note: I have edited the question to typeset it in MathJax. I've changed "$A, B \in \Bbb R^n$" to "$A, B \subset \Bbb R^n$" which is what I presume OP meant.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, the sum of two compact spaces clearly has a finite subcover for every open cover, i.e. the union of two finite subcovers for each of its components.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof You are mistaking $A+B$ for $A \cup B$. Please read OP's definition of $A+B$.

Comment: But an open cover of $A+B$ isn’t necessarily even a cover of $A$ or $B$, so how do you use those to get the subcover?

Answer (score 4):

- The set $A\times B\subset{\mathbb R}^{2n}$ is compact.
- The map $\quad {\rm add}: \ A\times B\to {\mathbb R}^n,\quad (a,b)\mapsto a+b\quad $ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Proof using sequential compactness: Suppose $a_k+b_k \to y$ where $a_k \in A$ and $b_k$ in $B$ for all $k$. There exists a subsequence $a_{k_i}$ converging to some point $a \in A$. Now look at $b_{k_i}$. This has a subsequence $b_{k_{i_l}}$ converging to some $b$ in $B$. Can you now show that $y=a+b$?